# Apply XML code to multiple xml elements

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm pretty new to android development and I was wondering if there is a way you can apply xml code to multiple elements. For intance, from a css background you can do the following.

```
.dog, #cat, .fish {color:#blue}
```

and the color blue will be applied to the objects dog, cat and fish. This is not only easy to type but also makes your code clean

So I was wondering if the same could be applied to XML/Java code

```
<EditText
android:hint="dog" 
android:textSize="15dp"
/>

<EditText
android:hint="cat" 
android:textSize="15dp" />
```

instead of repeating  **android:textSize="15dp"**

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this results by following the [styles and themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) documentation. Let me give you a quick guide:

1. First navigate to styles.xml `res->value->styles.xml`
2. Type the following:

> ```
> <style name="YourName">
>     <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
> </style>
> ```

3. Then navigate to xml page which has the code you want to clean up: `res->layout->YourCodeName.xml`
4. Do this:

`<EditText
      android:hint="cat"  style="@style/YourName" />`

`<EditText
    android:hint="dog" 
    style="@style/YourName" />`

BTW it's better to use `sp` for text size not `dp`
read more about android styles and themes here:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm
2. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Read the official Android [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) documentation. You could come up with something like:

Style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="SomeName">
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout:

```
<EditText
    android:hint="dog" 
    style="SomeName" />

<EditText
    android:hint="cat" 
    style="SomeName" />
```

Of course, it can get much more complex then that. But this is basic Android 101 if you read the standard Android documentation.